# Unable to propose Gnosis txn using sdk

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis, gnosis-chain

```
import SafeApiKit from "@safe-global/api-kit";
import Safe, { SafeFactory } from "@safe-global/protocol-kit";
import { SafeTransactionDataPartial } from "@safe-global/safe-core-sdk-types";
import { Web3Adapter } from "@safe-global/protocol-kit";

import { ethers } from "ethers";
import { EthersAdapter } from "@safe-global/protocol-kit";
import Web3 from "web3";

const INFURA_URL = "infura url";
const SAFE_ADDRESS = "0xcFE698D4a58AaC1B9E21Ab2525f737384911294F";
const signerAddress = "0x4b14Bdf9f79d041817923aBAF0AAe5fa021136EE";

async function proposeTx() {
  const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(INFURA_URL);
  const web3 = new Web3(provider);

  const ethAdapter = new Web3Adapter({
    web3,
    signerAddress,
  });

  const txServiceUrl = "https://safe-transaction-goerli.safe.global";
  const safeService = new SafeApiKit({ txServiceUrl, ethAdapter });
  const safeSdk = await Safe.create({ ethAdapter, safeAddress: SAFE_ADDRESS });

  const safeTransactionData: SafeTransactionDataPartial = {
    to: "0xB446DA92B6B03b2916090499A6640889ccd41977",
    data: "0x",
    value: "100000000000000",
    nonce:4
  };

  const safeTransaction = await safeSdk.createTransaction({
    safeTransactionData,
  });

  console.log({ safeTransaction });

  const nonce = await safeService.getNextNonce(SAFE_ADDRESS);
  console.log({ nonce });

  const safeTxHash = await safeSdk.getTransactionHash(safeTransaction);
  console.log({ safeTxHash });

  const senderSignature = await safeSdk.signTransactionHash(safeTxHash);

  
  await safeService.proposeTransaction({
    safeAddress: SAFE_ADDRESS,
    safeTransactionData: safeTransaction.data,
    safeTxHash,
    senderAddress: signerAddress,
    senderSignature: senderSignature.data,
    origin:"console",
  });
}

proposeTx();
```

I have been trying to integrate the gnosis-safe sdk to broadcast the transaction.
But the unable to get the senderSignature

```
https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/blob/main/guides/integrating-the-safe-core-sdk.md
```

I had used this doc as reference.

```
var err = new Error('Returned error: ' + message);
                      ^
    Error: Returned error: The method eth_sign does not exist/is not available
        at Object.ErrorResponse (/Users/seetharamangr/Seetha/POC's/gnosis/multisig-sdk/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:28:19)
        at /Users/seetharamangr/Seetha/POC's/gnosis/multisig-sdk/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:300:36
        at /Users/seetharamangr/Seetha/POC's/gnosis/multisig-sdk/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js:127:13
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
      data: null
    }
```

we also get the error while getting the signature

Comment: You seem to be passing a web3.js provider object without a signing key. You need to load it from a mnemonic phrase or a private key.